# In Kubuntu, how do I start a new instance from taskbar with meta+shift+number?

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, taskbar

In Ubuntu or Windows, I can press `win/super/meta`+`shift`+`number` to open a new application instance that is pinned to the taskbar (the number denotes which app to open). But after I switched to Kubuntu-desktop, this combination does not work. The only thing that works is `meta`+`number` opens a new instance if no instance is already opened; and switches to the opened instance if there already is one. Adding `shift` to this combination does nothing.

I found no corresponding items in shortcut settings. How I do configure KDE to open a new instance with `meta`+`shift`+`number`?

System specs (if it matters):

- Kubuntu 20.04
- KDE Plasma 5.18.5
- KDE Framework 5.68.0
- Qt 5.12.8
- Kernel 5.11.0-34-generic